# Poll on HttpOutboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageHandlerSpec documentumPolledInbound() {
    return Http
        .outboundGateway("/fintegration/getReadyForReimInvoices/Cz", restTemplate)
        .expectedResponseType(String.class)
        .errorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler())
        ; 
}
```

How to poll the above, to get the payload for further processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP Client endpoint is not pollable, but event-driven. So, as you usually call some REST Service from the `curl`, for example, the same way happens here. You have some `.handle()`, I guess, for this `documentumPolledInbound()` and there is some message channel to send message to trigger this endpoint to call your REST service.

Not clear how you are going to handle a response, but there is rally a way to trigger an event periodically to call this endpoint.

For that purpose we only can * mock* an inbound channel adapter which can configured with some trigger policy:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpPollingFlow() {    
    return IntegrationFlows
                    .from(() -> "", e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                    .handle(documentumPolledInbound())
                    .get();
}
```

This way we are going to send a message with an empty string as a payload to the channel for the `handle()`. And we do that every 10 seconds.

Since your `HttpMessageHandlerSpec` doesn't care about an inbound payload, it is really doesn't matter what we return from the `MessageSource` in the polling channel adapter.